# Game on blockchain in solidity

Tags: solidity, blockchain, nft

I want to make on-blockchain game with 10k NFTs. NFT works like faucets, giving one of few ERC20 tokens, or works as swap - if someone have this NFT he can swap ERC20 token into another. Is it possible?

Comment: Give a look at the erc1155 contract, it mixes tokens with nfts. Perhaps it can do what you want.

Comment: @JoãoPauloMorais thank you very much!